# How to PyQt5 make a QTreeView item both disabled and unselectable?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 application which contains a `QTreeView` to which I plugged a `QAbstractItemModel`-based class. I would like to disable some of the items of the tree  **but also** to make them unselectable. To do so, I implemented the `flags` method like so:

```
   def flags(self,index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

        # This is the condition for disabling an item and make it unselectable
        node = self.data(index,QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1)
        if isinstance(node,h5py.Dataset):
            if len(node.shape) > 1:
                return super(NeXuSTreeModel,self).flags(index) & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

The result is half-way. Indeed, the corresponding items are disabled (they are displayed in grey) but still they are selectable. Would you know what is wrong with my implementation of the `flags` method ?

Comment: By "still they are selectable" do you mean that you can click them and they appear as selected? Btw, note that by default a QAbstractItemModel returns both `ItemIsEnabled` and `ItemIsSelectable`, so there's little point in negating those flags: just return `Qt.NoItemFlags`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The relevant items are both disabled and unselectable when the `ItemIsEnabled` and `ItemIsSelectable` are removed. This is using qt-5.15.6 on linux. Please state your qt version and platform, and also provide a proper [mre].

Comment: in fact, the item can not be selected in the sense that it is not highlighted but still the selection event is triggered and this is that event that I want to disable. I thought that it was the purpose of negating the `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable`

Comment: Do you mean signals like `activated`, `clicked` and `doubleClicked`? I agree that emitting these for disabled items is questionable behaviour. The docs state that `ItemIsEnabled` means "The user can interact with the item". But this is clearly false, since unsetting it doesn't prevent interaction with the mouse (i.e. the signals are still emitted). I suppose the reasoning is that it allows for greater flexibility, in that you can choose whether to handle those signals or not (depending on the current state of the flags). But  keyboard interaction is completely prevented, so why not the mouse?